# suse linux 11 unable to ping target machine

Tags: networking, ping, suse

i have four suse linux servers siting on different lan. they are connected by a router and it is configured to allow these machines to ping one another.

default routings have been added to all these machines. the problem is:
1) machine A can ping to machine B and D
2) machine B,C and D can ping to machine A
why can't machine A ping C?

I troubleshoot by setting up machine E on the same lan as machine A, and set machine A ip address on machine E (disabled machine NIC card during this test). i was able to ping machine B,C and D on machine E.

they are not sitting behind any firewall. i have flush all ip tables for these machines. i have turned off all OS firewall.

Comment: What are the subnets of the machines ?

Comment: machine A and E are in 10.6.10; machine B is 10.6.20, C in 10.6.30 and D in 10.6.40